# Sql Express 2005: Restore backup to given time

Tags: sql-server-2005

I successfully deleted all records from a table in a database.
I have a 18h old full backup + the transaction log.
The database backup is FULL, the recovery model is SIMPLE.

Is it possible to "roll back" this delete from the log?

I've tried restoring this database to another name with a time before the delete event, but it keeps returning 0 rows in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you will be able to do is restore to the 18h old full backup. You will not be able to recover the data in the transaction log, [because it is simple and not FULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx).

Comment: I answer this through experience, and feel your pain.